# how to prevent duplicate records inserted in db while using hibernate many to many annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

Adding user works fine.
problem faced is
Tasks are being added n corresponding users are also being added but 'everytime a new user is being added' even if he exists in Users table. This is leading to mismatching of taskid n userid in the Bridge table..can anyone help me on this...its really imp....below r my POJOS Users n Tasks. calling is done by a JSP file...waiting for any help on it!!!!

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="Tasks")
public class Tasks implements Serializable
{
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "t_Id")
private int Id;
@Column (name = "t_Name")
private String TaskName;
@Column (name = "t_Details")
private String TaskDetails;
@Column (name = "t_Status")
private int TaskStatus;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = org.Users.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade =       {CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.PERSIST})
//@Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "user_Tasks", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "t_Id")},  inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "u_Id")})
private Set <Users> users = new HashSet<Users>(0);

public Tasks(){}
public Tasks(String TaskName) {
    this.TaskName = TaskName;
}

public Tasks( String TaskName, String TaskDetails, int TaskStatus) {
    this.TaskName = TaskName;
    this.TaskDetails = TaskDetails;
    this.TaskStatus = TaskStatus;
}

public Tasks(String TaskName, String TaskDetails, int TaskStatus, Set<Users> users)
{
    this.TaskName = TaskName;
    this.TaskDetails = TaskDetails;
    this.TaskStatus = TaskStatus;
    this.users = users;
}
public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
 public void setId(int Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}
public String getTaskName() {
    return TaskName;
}
 public void setTaskName(String TaskName) {
    this.TaskName = TaskName;
}
public String getTaskDetails() {
    return TaskDetails;
}
public void setTaskDetails(String TaskDetails) {
    this.TaskDetails = TaskDetails;
}
 public int getTaskStatus() {
    return TaskStatus;
}
public void setTaskStatus(int TaskStatus) {
    this.TaskStatus = TaskStatus;
}
public Set<Users> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
public void setUsers(Set<Users> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

}
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users implements Serializable {
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "u_Id")
private int Id;
@Column (name ="u_Name")        
private String Name;
@Column (name ="u_Username")
private String Username;
@Column (name="u_Password")
private String password;
@ManyToMany(targetEntity =org.Tasks.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="users", cascade ={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.PERSIST})
// @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "user_Tasks", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "u_Id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "t_Id")})
private Set<Tasks> task = new HashSet<Tasks>();
public Users(){}
public Users(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

public int getId() {
    return Id;
}
public void setId(int Id) {
    this.Id = Id;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
 public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return Username;
}
public void setUsername(String Username) {
    this.Username = Username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}  
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Set<Tasks> getTask() {
    return task;
}

public void setTask(Set<Tasks> task) {
    this.task = task;
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 7;
    hash = 19 * hash + (this.Name != null ? this.Name.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 19 * hash + (this.Username != null ? this.Username.hashCode() : 0);
    hash = 19 * hash + (this.password != null ? this.password.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
 }
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Users other = (Users) obj;
    if ((this.Name == null) ? (other.Name != null) : !this.Name.equals(other.Name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.Username == null) ? (other.Username != null) : !this.Username.equals(other.Username)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ((this.password == null) ? (other.password != null) : !this.password.equals(other.password)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }

}

public class ManageTasks

  public static void main(String arg[])
  {
  try
  {
  SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addPackage("org").addAnnotatedClass(Tasks.class).addAnnotatedClass(Users.class).buildSessionFactory();        
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
  System.out.println(e);
  }

  }
  public Integer addTasks(String TaskName, String TaskDetails, int  TaskStatus, Set use)
   {
  SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addPackage("org").addAnnotatedClass(Tasks.class).addAnnotatedClass(Users.class).buildSessionFactory();
  Session session = factory.openSession();
  Transaction tx = null;
  Integer taskID = null;
  try
  {  
      tx = session.beginTransaction();  
      Tasks task = new Tasks(TaskName, TaskDetails, TaskStatus);
      task.setUsers(use);

      session.save(task);
      tx.commit();      
  }catch(HibernateException e)
  {
  if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally
          {
              session.close();
          }    
  return taskID;
  }      
  public void addUser(String name, String username, String password)
{
   SessionFactory factory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addPackage("org").addAnnotatedClass(Users.class).
                   buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = null;
    session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    Integer userID = null;  
  try
  {
     tx = session.beginTransaction();
     Users user = new Users();
     user.setName(name);
     user.setUsername(username);
     user.setPassword(password);
     userID = (Integer) session.save(user); 
     tx.commit();
  }catch (HibernateException e)
  {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     e.printStackTrace(); 
  }
  finally
  {
     session.close(); 
  }

 }
```

here is the AddTask calling code

```
String taskname = request.getParameter("taskname");
String taskdetails = request.getParameter("taskdetails");
tring user1 = request.getParameter("user1");
String user2 = request.getParameter("user2");
String user3 = request.getParameter("user3");
Set <Users> user = new HashSet <Users>();
user.add(new Users(user1));
user.add(new Users(user2));
user.add(new Users(user3));
nt TaskStatus;
if(taskname == null && taskdetails == null)
TaskStatus = 0;
else
TaskStatus = 1;

ManageTasks mt = new ManageTasks();
mt.addTasks(taskname, taskdetails, TaskStatus, user);
out.println("Sucessfully added!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the task you need to add users retrieved from DB which already have an id. This way Hibernate will not insert new users, but only entries in the join table when the task entity is persisted.

In your code to create a new task you have to find an existing user instead of creating a new one. So you should write a method `findUserByName(String name)` to retrieve the user from DB and replace:
`user.add(new Users(user1));`
with:
`user.add(findUserByName(user1));`

Comment: yes i tried it but i cant remove this error. Can u suggest the piece of code i must change in my file....i need it so urgently..... by the way thanxx for ur help but i need a bit more help...

Comment: I think the problem is in the code that calls addTask. Post that code if you need additional help.

Comment: i couldn't make it work....maybe i implemented the method wrong coz it's again not working....:(. It's my first time with hibernate so i think i need more help!!!